# How can I change the android:windowBackground?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, android-theme, android-styles

So I'm trying to use a custom theme for my android app made with unity, the idea is to change the color (or even add an image) while the app is loading (before unity logo) since some lower-end devices are taking up to 10 seconds to show the splash and a 10 seconds blackscreen just makes it look like the app is broken.

So far my android manifest has:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
```

I have another file with the styles:

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/editor_bg</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Whenever I change the style's parent, say to Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar, I see the change, my app removes the black screen so I know the style It's been changed/used.

My problem is that @drawable/editor_bg doesn't seem to work at all, I even tried to use a color instead of an image with @color/white, defined in another file.

Not sure if it is a problem with unity itself (using version 5.3.1 personal) or missing something on android side. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<resources> 
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"> 
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/editor_bg</item>
<item name="?windowBackground">@drawable/editor_bg</item>  
</style> 
</resources>
```

Comment: This one just gives me an error
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr '?windowBackground'

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it programmatically:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.editor_bg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see a code here 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2_r1/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java#2834

```
mBackgroundResource = a.getResourceId(
com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowBackground, 0);

mDecor.setWindowBackground(drawable);

public void setWindowBackground(Drawable drawable) {
    if (getBackground() != drawable) {
        setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```